# Compare elements in the list

Tags: scheme

I need compare every second element in the list but I don't know how. Here is an example:

```
(compare? '(1 x 2 x 3 x 4)) -> #t
(compare? '(1 x 2 x 3 o)) -> #f
```

I can only compare second and fourth element:

```
(define compare?
  (lambda (list)
    (equal? (cadr list) (cadddr list))))
```

I need 6th, 8th, 10th etc.... I don't know length of the list. Please, help me.

Comment: Here's a hint: lists have structural induction. That means that you don't need to address the 6th, 8th, 10th, etc. directly. They can all be seen the same way as the 2nd.

Comment: I tried to add (compare? (cddr list)), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer, filling-in the blanks:

```
(define (compare? lst)
  (if <???> ; if the list has at most two elements
      #t    ; then return true
      (let ((elt (cadr lst)))        ; grab the first element to be compared
        (let loop ((lst (cddr lst))) ; step on the second group of elements
          (cond (<???> #t)           ; if there's only one or zero elements left
                (<???> #f)           ; if the second element is not equal to `elt`
                (else (loop (cddr lst)))))))) ; otherwise continue iterating
```

Comment: Ah, the left-fold solution. I was wondering whether someone would post that. I felt that a right-fold solution was more "structurally inductive" so I chose that approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the example of `(compare? '(1 x 2 x 3 x 4))`.

You want to ensure that `(compare? '(2 x 3 x 4))` is true, and that the `1 x` before that also matches.

That then means that you want to ensure that `(compare? '(3 x 4))` is true (which it is, by definition), and that the `2 x` before that also matches.

Notice how we are working with smaller and smaller lists each time. We can do that because lists have structural induction. Because of structural induction, you don't actually have to know the length of the list. The algorithm just works on smaller and smaller sublists until it hits a base case.

---

Sample skeletal solution (fill in the `<???>` with suitable code):

```
(define (compare? lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
      #t
      (let ((item (cadr lst))
            (next (compare? (cddr lst))))
        (case next
          ((#f) <???>)
          ((#t) <???>)
          (else (and <???> <???>))))))
```

(Technically the `#f` clause is not necessary, but, it may make it clearer to you what the solution approach should be.)

This solution will only work correctly if the matched slots in the list are not `#t` or `#f`. Since you're using symbols in your example, it will work correctly.